# Save PDF data fields to MS SQL Database

Tags: asp.net, .net, pdf, sharepoint, adobe

We have a fillable PDF form that is stored in Sharepoint 2010.

When users click the save button on that PDF, I'd like to extract the data they input, and somehow save it to a SQL database.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the save button a button on the PDF form or do you refer to the save button/menu item of the PDF reader?

Comment: Well, that's a good question, as there isn't :) Just trying to figure out some way to accomplish this. Basically, I'm trying to prevent having to create a .NET form to replicate this fillable PDF form.